# Problem with CSR 5 Cambridge Silicon Radio and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, usb, bluetooth

My Bluetooth CRS 5.0 dongle doesn't work on my Linux Ubuntu 20.04.

Details:

```
Linux version 5.8.0-50-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-030) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021
```

`dmesg | grep Blue` returns:

```
[    5.764592] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.764617] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.764620] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.764621] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.764623] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.911291] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
[    8.639737] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.639739] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.639743] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  784.333915] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
[  845.465865] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
[  881.856734] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
[ 1051.635612] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
[ 1060.631971] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
```

`bluetoothctl` returns:

```
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]#
```

`lsmod | grep -i blue` returns:

```
bluetooth             581632  16 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
```

`hcitool dev` returns:

```
Devices:
```

`hciconfig hci0 up` returns:

```
Can't init device hci0: Invalid argument (22)
```

and in parallel to it `btmon` returns:

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.53
= Note: Linux version 5.8.0-50-generic (x86_64)                                                                                                                        0.183374
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                                                                                               0.183375
= New Index: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:12 (Primary,USB,hci0)                                                                                                               [hci0] 0.183376
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.17                                                                                                             {0x0001} 0.183376
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.17                                                                                                                  {0x0002} 0.183387
@ RAW Open: hciconfig (privileged) version 2.22                                                                                                               {0x0003} 2.733603
= Open Index: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:12                                                                                                                                 [hci0] 2.800107
= Index Info: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:12 (Cambridge Silicon Radio)                                                                                                       [hci0] 2.800123
< HCI Command: Read Local Version Information (0x04|0x0001) plen 0                                                                                           #1 [hci0] 2.800170
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 12                                                                                                                 #2 [hci0] 2.802164
      Read Local Version Information (0x04|0x0001) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        HCI version: Bluetooth 4.0 (0x06) - Revision 12576 (0x3120)
        LMP version: Bluetooth 4.0 (0x06) - Subversion 8891 (0x22bb)
        Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
< HCI Command: Reset (0x03|0x0003) plen 0                                                                                                                    #3 [hci0] 2.802371
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                                                  #4 [hci0] 2.813177
      Reset (0x03|0x0003) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: Read Local Supported Features (0x04|0x0003) plen 0                                                                                            #5 [hci0] 2.813299
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 12                                                                                                                 #6 [hci0] 2.816138
      Read Local Supported Features (0x04|0x0003) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Features: 0xbf 0x3e 0x4d 0xfa 0xdb 0x3d 0x7b 0xc7
          3 slot packets
          5 slot packets
          Encryption
          Slot offset
          Timing accuracy
          Role switch
          Sniff mode
          Power control requests
          Channel quality driven data rate (CQDDR)
          SCO link
          HV2 packets
          HV3 packets
          CVSD synchronous data
          Power control
          Transparent synchronous data
          Flow control lag (most significant bit)
          Enhanced Data Rate ACL 2 Mbps mode
          Enhanced inquiry scan
          Interlaced inquiry scan
          Interlaced page scan
          RSSI with inquiry results
          Extended SCO link (EV3 packets)
          EV4 packets
          EV5 packets
          AFH capable slave
          AFH classification slave
          LE Supported (Controller)
          3-slot Enhanced Data Rate ACL packets
          5-slot Enhanced Data Rate ACL packets
          Pause encryption
          AFH capable master
          AFH classification master
          Enhanced Data Rate eSCO 2 Mbps mode
          Extended Inquiry Response
          Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR (Controller)
          Secure Simple Pairing
          Encapsulated PDU
          Erroneous Data Reporting
          Non-flushable Packet Boundary Flag
          Link Supervision Timeout Changed Event
          Inquiry TX Power Level
          Enhanced Power Control
          Extended features
          Unknown features (0x4000000000000000)
< HCI Command: Read Local Version Information (0x04|0x0001) plen 0                                                                                           #7 [hci0] 2.816259
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 12                                                                                                                 #8 [hci0] 2.817971
      Read Local Version Information (0x04|0x0001) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        HCI version: Bluetooth 4.0 (0x06) - Revision 12576 (0x3120)
        LMP version: Bluetooth 4.0 (0x06) - Subversion 8891 (0x22bb)
        Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
< HCI Command: Read BD ADDR (0x04|0x0009) plen 0                                                                                                             #9 [hci0] 2.818052
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 10                                                                                                                #10 [hci0] 2.819970
      Read BD ADDR (0x04|0x0009) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:12 (cyber-blue(HK)Ltd)
< HCI Command: Read Buffer Size (0x04|0x0005) plen 0                                                                                                        #11 [hci0] 2.820100
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 11                                                                                                                #12 [hci0] 2.821968
      Read Buffer Size (0x04|0x0005) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        ACL MTU: 679  ACL max packet: 8
        SCO MTU: 48   SCO max packet: 16
< HCI Command: Read Class of Device (0x03|0x0023) plen 0                                                                                                    #13 [hci0] 2.822051
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7                                                                                                                 #14 [hci0] 2.824011
      Read Class of Device (0x03|0x0023) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Class: 0x000000
          Major class: Miscellaneous
          Minor class: 0x00
< HCI Command: Read Local Name (0x03|0x0014) plen 0                                                                                                         #15 [hci0] 2.824129
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 252                                                                                                               #16 [hci0] 2.841133
      Read Local Name (0x03|0x0014) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Name: CSR8510 A10

< HCI Command: Read Voice Setting (0x03|0x0025) plen 0                                                                                                      #17 [hci0] 2.841264
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 6                                                                                                                 #18 [hci0] 2.843026
      Read Voice Setting (0x03|0x0025) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Setting: 0x0000
          Input Coding: Linear
          Input Data Format: 1's complement
          Input Sample Size: 8-bit
          # of bits padding at MSB: 0
          Air Coding Format: CVSD
< HCI Command: Read Number of Supported IAC (0x03|0x0038) plen 0                                                                                            #19 [hci0] 2.843120
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 5                                                                                                                 #20 [hci0] 2.845170
      Read Number of Supported IAC (0x03|0x0038) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Number of IAC: 2
< HCI Command: Read Current IAC LAP (0x03|0x0039) plen 0                                                                                                    #21 [hci0] 2.845289
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 8                                                                                                                 #22 [hci0] 2.847021
      Read Current IAC LAP (0x03|0x0039) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Number of IAC: 1
        Access code: 0x9e8b33 (General Inquiry)
< HCI Command: Set Event Filter (0x03|0x0005) plen 1                                                                                                        #23 [hci0] 2.847109
        Type: Clear All Filters (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                                                                 #24 [hci0] 2.849172
      Set Event Filter (0x03|0x0005) ncmd 1
        Status: Invalid HCI Command Parameters (0x12)
= Close Index: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:12                                                                                                                                [hci0] 2.849251
@ RAW Close: hciconfig
```

PS: A very important detail is that my Geforce 1050 does not run on the new Linux kernel I tried to update to. My video doesn't work after updating to the new and second last kernel.

Comment: *Unbranded CSR clone detected* means it's a fake so anything can happen. Regarding your Nvidia that would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same problem.

Move the following to another place:

```
/lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_config.bin
/lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin
```

Create links:

```
cd /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/
ln -s rtl8761bu_fw.bin rtl8761b_fw.bin
ln -s rtl8761bu_config.bin rtl8761b_config.bin
```

- Based on this topic: https://fosspost.org/fix-bluetooth-rtl8761b-problem-on-linux-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: The `move to another place` can be something like `cd /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/ mv rtl8761b_config.bin rtl8761b_config.old` etc.